# php appends Â when i use ® character while email sending

Tags: php, email, utf-8

I want to send email that contains special character like ®.When i send the email whit content type html and charset utf-8 it displays the email like this Â®.Any suggestion to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that you didn’t specify the character encoding properly.

Comment: I use php mailer class so it is long issue to mention about that.Let me explain the operation:First,i send the data to my php file with ajax.And then i echo the data on the page in order to see whether it is sending correct value or not.It sends the correct value.Also it writes the correct value to database too.But it doesnt send correct email.It attaches Â character to ®

Answer (score 1):

You say specifying UTF-8 doesn't work for you, but please provide some code in case we can see that you've done something wrong.

In the meanwhile, since you're sending HTML, you could simply replace the ® with the HTML entity code - `&reg;` (or the numeric alternative `&#174;`).